# Tangent Lines Circle Problem

Tags: geometry

$PP1, QQ1$ - tangent lines. Given that $PP1 = a, QQ1 = b$, find $PQ$.

[image]

Comment: Are angles PDQ and PBQ right angles or is that just coincidental?

Comment: It's a coincidence. Points A, B, C, D are randomly placed.

Comment: At this point I think the Steiner theorem should be used.

Comment: I would suggest Steiner is a red herring.  Produce PP' and QQ' to meet at X.  Since for any given position of p' and Q' (assuming the circle to be given) there will be a fixed angle at X it should then be possible to calculate PQ by trig.   That PQ is determined by the angle at X can be easily seen if you move P' or Q' around the perimeter of the circle.  The basic diagram remains valid but PQ varies in length between a + b when X is 180 , the diameter of the circle when PP' and QQ' are parallel and a~b when PP' meet QQ' .

Comment: If all you know is $a$ and $b$, there is no way you'll be able to find $PQ$. You've got two random points on some random circle.  $PQ$ can be anything.